# from xml to json formatting

Tags: php, xml, json, domdocument

Hi i need some help i have the following code

```
    $producers = simplexml_import_dom($xmlDoc);
    $file = fopen('producers.json','w');
    foreach( $producers as $producer)
    {
       $info[] = $producer; 
    }
    $jsonInfo = json_encode($info);
    fwrite($file, $jsonInfo);
    fclose($file);
```

this outputs

[{"id":"8","name":"Em\u00e5mejeriet","street":" Grenv\u00e4gen 1-3\n\t\t\t\t\t","postal":" 577 39\n\t\t\t\t\t","city":" Hultsfred\n\t\t\t\t","weburl":"http://www.emamejeriet.se","logourl":"http://172.16.206.1/~thajo/1DV449/laboration01/producenter/images/ema.png"},{"id":"57","name":"\u00d6lands \u00f6rtag\u00e5rd","street":" Stora Fr\u00f6 2393 \n\t\t\t\t\t","postal":" 380 62\n\t\t\t\t\t","city":" M\u00f6rbyl...and so on

I need som help to format it, i need to get rid of the newlines and format it to more readable json format. aswell I cannot get the UTF-8 to work.

/thanks

Comment: use the trim() function before setting $info[]

Comment: preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t]/', ' ', trim($data));

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

PHP 5.4 offers the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option for use with the json_encode() call.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

OR

```
 $string = '{"a":"apple","b":"banana","c":"catnip"}';
 $pattern = array(',"', '{', '}');
 $replacement = array(",\n\t\"", "{\n\t", "\n}");
 echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: I get the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT to work, but none of the preg replace, trim and str_replace doea anything for the documetnt, maby because of that the $producer is an object not a string?

Comment: I got it to work ealier in my code, where i create the xml document, I trimmed away the whitespaces and it worked, but i still cant figure out why the encoding don't work..

Comment: I use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
but instead of getting like
"name": "Emåmejeriet",
I get
"name": "EmÃ¥mejeriet",

In my browser